# HP Hotkey UWP Service: Fn is not working for brightness increasing/decreasing

Tags: windows-10, laptop, hotkeys, brightness, fn-key

I'm using HP Probook 440 G4 for last 3 months. And I couldn't increase/decrease brightness using Fn+F5/F6. Every time I tried, it said something like this.

> [Window name] HP Hotkey UWP Service
>
> Error: HP Software Framework is not installed in the system 
> Please download and install from the link - 
> ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-sofpaq/cmit/softpaq/CASLSetup.exe
> Note: Restart system after installation

The link suggested here is not valid anymore. What can I do?

Comment: Get the HP Driver Update Application, run it and update all Drivers.  It appears your Hotkey Driver is out of date or had some other problem. Updating all Drivers should fix this

Comment: Yap, I solved it and posted this question to share that as I got some pain for this. Thanks for your idea. May it also helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Actually that link is valid but you have to call it with the http protocol like so: https://ftp.hp.com/pub/caps-softpaq/cmit/softpaq/CASLSetup.exe. This installs the HP Software Framework and the HP CASL Framework Service, which, when running, enables hotkey support.

Comment: I've been trying in vain to find information on what the CASL service does (including what on earth CASL stands for.) Do you have a source for *" the HP CASL Framework Service ... enables hotkey support"*?

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried something from the internet. And finally solved the problem and that is how.

If you've not installed HP Support Assistant yet, please install it from their [website](https://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/hpsupportassistant/hpsupport.html) and restart it.
It should be solved. But if not (that's my case), then go to windows searchbar and type `Services`. Go there, find `HP Hotkey UWP Service`, right click, stop it first and start it again. And Fn is working fine in my laptop. 
There may be another solution like - Hotkey driver update etc. So, it may help.

Comment: If I post my first comment as an answer, do you find it helpful?

Comment: Actually I've tried mine. So, if your solution comes first in my mind or the internet, maybe I'll try yours. But your solution seems helpful to me. So, maybe some others will be helped.

Answer (score -1):

super,

thx

"But if not (that's my case), then go to windows searchbar and type Services. Go there, find HP Hotkey UWP Service, right click, stop it first and start it again. And Fn is working fine in my laptop."

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1129791)